# Including template files and dynamically changing variables within them

Tags: php, function, templates

To make life a little easier for myself I would like to build a very simple template engine for my projects. Something I had in mind was to have .html files in a directory that get included to a page using PHP when I want them. So a typical `index.php` would look like this:

```
<?php

IncludeHeader("This is the title of the page");
IncludeBody("This is some body content");
IncludeFooter();

?>
```

Something along those lines, and then in my template files I'd have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{PAGE_TITLE}</title>
</head>
<body>
```

But one thing I can't work out how to do is get the parameter passed to the functions and replace `{PAGE_TITLE}` with it.

Does anyone have a solution or perhaps a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of keeping things simple, why not just use .php files with PHP shorttags instead of `{PAGE_TITLE}` or the like?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=$PAGE_TITLE?></title>
</head>
<body>
```

Then, to isolate the variable space, you can create a template load function which works like this:

```
function load_template($path, $vars) {
    extract($vars);
    include($path);
}
```

Where $vars is an associative array with keys equal to variable names, and values equal to variable values.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use php?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=$pageTitle; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is something like this:

```
<?php
function IncludeHeader($title)
{
    echo str_replace('{PAGE_TITLE}', $title, file_get_contents('header.html'));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may understand, PHP is, itself, a template engine.  That being said, there are several projects that add the type of templating you're describing.  One which you might want to investigate is [Smarty Templates](http://www.smarty.net/).  You might also want to check out the [article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/beyond-template-engine) published at [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com) describing templating engines in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is the trick I've seen some frameworks use:

```
// Your function call
myTemplate('header',
    array('pageTitle' => 'My Favorite Page',
          'email' => 'joe@bob.com',
    )
);

// the function
function myTemplate($filename, $variables) {
    extract($variables);
    include($filename);
}

// the template:
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=$pageTitle?></title>
</head>
<body>
    Email me here<a href="mailto:<?=$email?>"><?=$email?></a>
</body>
</html>
```